# Can I use RDF/SPARQL queries to retrieve information from research papers?

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have basic knowledge on RDF and thus I don't know whether this is possible. I'm doing research on research papers that use meta-analysis. With the help of the [PROV model](https://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/), I want to run SPARQL queries that will retrieve relevant information about the meta-analysis. I was hoping I could use RDF/SPARQL to make the process of finding and organizing the relevant information less time consuming.

Now, my question is:

I'm assuming that I need to write something like [this RDF code](https://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/#narrative-example-simple-1) first, and then run a SPARQL query on it in order to retrieve/show the relevant information (this RDF code of course has nothing to do with meta-analysis, but I wanted to show an example that uses the PROV ontology). The RDF code will be slightly different for every research paper. Since I want to answer the same questions, the subject and predicate will stay the same, but the value will differ each time. Ideally, I would like to make a 'global' RDF code, that is easily applicable on every meta-analysis, thus not having to fill in the values part of the RDF triple manually (since the value part will be different for each research paper, I would like the value part of the triple to automatically change depending on the research paper).
Is there a way that the computer will be able to retrieve the relevant value by itself in the pdf file/website(where the research is found) and then store this in the RDF, so that I don't have to look up this value and put it in the RDF code myself?

Comment: what do you want to "leave empty"? I don't get it. The only thing I understood is that you want to generate RDF data for some research papers such that you could later on use SPARQL to query the data.

Comment: @UninformedUser sorry if that wasn't clear, I'll edit my original post. I meant that I myself fill in the subject and the predicate of the RDF, but not the value. Then I was wondering whether it's possible (maybe with machine learning? data mining?) that the computer finds the value in the pdf/website itself, so that the computer fills in the value part of the RDF triple.

Comment: what would be the value? I mean, you have a PDF file, ok. Do you mean the optional meta data of a PDF document? If so, which meta data? if not, what else? the meta data is basically XML, so if you know which fields, you could extract those.

Comment: @UninformedUser for example, I want to be able to answer the question: 'What is the true effect size?', which is calculated somewhere in the meta-analysis process. So I'm looking to retrieve information that's really stored inside the text of the pdf/website.

Comment: @UninformedUser for some more clarity, for that specific example the value would be a certain number that usually can be found at the end of the calculations, the subject would be 'effect size' and the predicate would be 'true'.

Comment: @UninformedUser I realize that the predicate and subject are not correct since I have to base them on the PROV ontology, but I hope that it is now clear what kind of values I want to retrieve.

Comment: you're talking about automatically extracting RDF triples out of text? Any kind of text?

Comment: @UninformedUser yes, that's what I'm talking about. But specifically extracting the last part of the triple, the value part. Because the subject and predicate will be the same for every paper that uses meta-analysis, only the values will differ each time.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an RDf question then per se. As @UninformedUser has identified: the thing you're asking about is how to extract a value from a certain part of a paper. The fact that you then put it in as an object in an RDF triple is kind of secondary. You could put the value in anything.

Comment: @NicholasCar I see, that makes sense. What kind of technique could I use to extract a certain value from a certain paper, when I have minimal programming knowledge?

Comment: @Zzz I'm afraid there may be no solution if you have limited programming knowledge! Extracting text parts out of unstructured, or semi-/loosely-structured text isn't exactly a beginners exercise!

Comment: The simplest way to get text parts out of text is with simple pattern matching - Regular Expressions etc. More advanced techniques use Natural Language Processing, if the source text is just "text". If the source is things like tables, you need to use document element measurement techniques (is the value I want always a certain distance form a section header etc.). Not exactly beginner stuff.